# jquery ui drag/drop getting position from multiple draggables

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a droppable container with >1 draggables in it. I want to simply be able to see the position of each draggable every time any one of them is dragged. Sounds easy, but I'm having a tough time figuring it out. Here's what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable({ containment: '#droppable' });
    $("#draggable2").draggable({ containment: '#droppable' });
    $("#droppable").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            document.getElementById('position1').value = ui.position.top + ', ' + ui.position.left; 
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Basically, where I have the position1 input id gathering the position, I want to have a second line do the same thing for the other draggable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you don't need to use the `ui` parameter. Since you know what elements are draggable, you can select them specifically and find their positions. Also, since you're using jQuery, do yourself a favor and replace `document.getElementById` with `$`. :-)

Comment: Thanks for helping me get in the right direction! Seems like I know what should be possible, just don't know the syntax or how to get there. I tried selection the draggable to get their positions, but wasn't getting anything until I did .position() rather than .position. Thanks! :)