# How to get the position of the preview of a draggable element when it's dropped in HTML5 DnD

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm doing a visual editor using HTML5 Drag and Drop and i need to drag an element set as draggable to a div who acts as a container.

Some browsers provides a kind of preview image that represents the element while i'm dragging it, and when i let the element in the container with the drop event, i need to get the position where the user wants to put him. The problem is that i don't know the position of the preview ghost provided by browsers, so i don't know where exactly the element should be positioned.

I used the mouse position but it's not what i wanted, because the mouse position is not ever the same as the preview's. Is there a way to get the current position of the preview of a dragging element?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using jQuery UI to do your DnD?  I'm not sure if you've considered that or not, but here are some resources that might help you in-case you do choose to do the jQuery UI route:

[jQuery UI Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) (also see Droppable)

[jquery ui drag/drop getting position from multiple draggables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646492/jquery-ui-drag-drop-getting-position-from-multiple-draggables)

Comment: I think this is more of a comment than an answer. The question asked specifically for HTML5 DnD. Besides, some people prefer the raw power of HTML5 DnD (despite its rough-spots) over the massive abstraction of JQuery UI DnD